# Install ElasticSearch APM

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04, kibana, apm

I am trying to setup ElasticSearch APM, my OS is Ubuntu 16.04,
I installed ElasticSearch and Kibana on the system,
**I am referring the following site for installation steps -**
https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2018/02/setup-kibana-elastisearch.html
**The installation commands for ElasticSearch and Kibana are as follows-**

**# Install Elasticsearch-6**

```
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.0.1.tar.gz
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
ls /etc/init.d/elasticsearch
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

## Change bind address and JVM heap option as per requirement

Change network.host to 0.0.0.0 in elasticsearch.yml and set -Xms 4g & -Xmx 4g in jvm.options

```
sudo vi /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
sudo vi /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
```

## Setting read replicas to 0 if you are creating single node cluster

`curl -XPUT H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings?preserve_existing=false' -d '{"index.number_of_replicas" : "0"}'`

## Install Kibana

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kibana
sudo service kibana restart
```

## Install nginx

```
sudo apt-get -y install nginx
```

## Add nginx config file for kibana

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.conf
```

Replace mykibana.com with your server_name or IP. We will setup auth in next step, hence we have placed a line for auth_basic in kibana.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mykibana.com;
    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

## Setup auth

After installing apache2-utils when you run htpasswd, it will ask for a password, provide a password. This username and password would be useful when you try to access kibana from browser.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users efkadmin
sudo service nginx restart
```

## Web view of Kibana

After successful Setup, hit http://localhost:5601.
 Put username and password and you will see kibana web as shown below.

## APM setup

After installing ElasticSearch and Kibana,
I am trying to install APM server into it.
I used the following commands to install it -

```
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/apm-server/apm-server-6.3.1-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i apm-server-6.3.1-amd64.deb
```

## Import dashboard -

**./apm-server setup**

**On firing the above command I get the following error -**

```
bash: ./apm-server: No such file or directory
```

**Please help to setup APM**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command following command is executed sucessfully

```
> sudo dpkg -i apm-server-6.3.1-amd64.deb
```

The apm-server must have been installed.
You are trying to run apm-server by **./apm-server**, where you specifying that the binary apm-server is present in current directory.
But that is not the case, by installing via dpkg cmd the package is installed somewhere in /usr directory.
So you just need to run **apm-server -e** cmd in the shell.
No need to add **./**

If you get permission deniod error.
Run the command with sudo

Comment: Hi, apm-server -e command worked, do you know how to further use it? will I see the results on KIbana or somewhere else?

Comment: I'll suggest to go through the official documentation.
[link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/index.html)